# Получение json из бд

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redbeanphp

В бд хранится данные в формате json, вот так выглядят `{"0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,": ""}` Мне нужно получить их и записать в массив js

Делаю AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: 'php/getLessonData.php',
      data: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
          alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

getLessonData.php:

```
<?php
require "db.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
  // Получаем id users чья ссесия
  $userid = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
  // Загружаем данные об этом user
  $user = R::Load('users', $userid);
  //подгружаем данные с таблицы Courses
  $course = R::load('courses', $userid);

  // ЗДЕСЬ записываем json из бд в переменную $lessonProgress
  // lesson_progress это то поле, где находится {"0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,": ""}
  $lessonProgress = $course->lesson_progress;
}
//Вот здесь если оставить json_decode то ответ от сервера получается(см ниже)
echo json_decode($lessonProgress);
?>
```

**Ответ при использовании json_decode:**

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

Полезная нагрузка ответа:

```
<br />
<b>Recoverable fatal error</b>:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in <b>W:\domains\appBL\php\getLessonData.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
```

> **var_dump**`(json_decode($lessonProgress))` **:**
>
> `object(stdClass)#21 (1) {   ["0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"]=>   string(0) "" }`

alert в ajax запросе возвращает [object Object]

---

**Ответ без использования json_decode**, т.е. просто `echo $lessonProgress;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> **var_dump**`$lessonProgress` **:** `string(25) "{"0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,": ""}"`

alert в ajax запросе не срабатывает

---

Что я делаю не так, как мне получить и записать эти данные в массив js?

Comment: стоп, а почему json_decode, вам нужно разбить строку на массив а потом конвертнуть в JSON и отправить, для этого используется json_encode

Comment: @RifmaMan мне получить с базы и вытянуть в Js

Comment: у вас там не массив закодирован, а объект, единственным ключом которого является строка с перечислением значений.

Comment: @teran вот таким запросом я заносил массив из js в базу `$course->lessonProgress = json_encode($data);` в data [0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,]

Comment: тут ключевым вопросом будет, что содержалось в этом `data`. Вернее сказать, понятно что там содержится. Формируете вы его как то криво.

Comment: @teran ответ на `echo json_encode($data);`    `{"0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,":""}`

Comment: еще раз - вы криво собираете "массив" перед тем как записать его в базу. Проблема в записи а не при выводе. И скорее всего на стороне JS, когда вы собрали данные и отправляете их в пхп.

Comment: @КириллМиронов давайте начнем не с того что нужно передать, а что нужно записать в базу, т.к. то, что у вас там сейчас это вообще непонятная информация для JSON

Comment: @RifmaMan передаю я массив lessonProgress который =  [0,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,] `$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../../php/setLessonData.php",
      data: lessonProgress,
      dataType: 'json',
    })`

Comment: @КириллМиронов давайте сделаем проще, вам нужно записать в базу 
одномерный массив [1,2,3,4,5] и потом к примеру его достать, так?

Comment: @RifmaMan да именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально вы неправильно записали массив в формате JSON в базу, соответственно и вернуть его не сможете.

Нужно передать массив в php в формате JSON, после использовать `json_encode($post)` и записать его в базу, в результате вы получите в базе строку `[1,2,3]`, которая соответствует формату.

Получить данные очень просто, вы вытаскиваете эту строку и безо всякого перевода (просто через `echo`) отправляете её уже в формате JSON.

Если же вы хотите сохранить ассоциативный массив, вам следует использовать другую конструкцию, к примеру сериализованный массив php

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, буду исходить из этого

Comment: как мне кажется этот вопрос вместе с ответом изначально следует удалить, и вернуться к предыдущему вопросу автора, где он спрашивает, как записать данные. В целом данный ответ не решает проблему от слова вообще.

Comment: @teran полностью согласен, проблема была в записи в бд

Comment: @teran не удаляется)

Comment: а все потому, что при ответе все стараются ублажить автора, и никто не думает, насколько осмысленным вообще является вопрос.